# Associating images with questions for a randomized test

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program to display a randomized test of questions with images.

The test has 10 questions. I also have 10 images added into an ImageList. My questions are randomly selected to be displayed for each quiz I resolve.  I would like to have each question with its picture.

I have a collection for questions that I load from a file:

```
Collection<question> questions = new Collection<question>();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("quiz.txt");
while (!sr.EndOfStream) 
{ 
    question i = new question();
    i.text = sr.ReadLine();
    questions.Add(i);
}
sr.Close(); 

Random r = new Random(); 
int x = r.Next(questions.Count);
```

I added the `ImageList` control from the toolbox.  Then I added images to it using the Images Collection Editor. For the code I used:

```
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[a];
```

This stops when `a > imageList1.Images.Count`

How could I make a correlation between current_question and its picture from ImageList?

***UPDATE***

```
 public class question
{
 public bool displayed = false;
 public string text, answer1, answer2;
}

 private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string line = questions[current_question].text;
        int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':');
        int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter));
        string questionText=line.Substring(delimiter + 1);
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imageIndex];//I still have problems with       
                                                          //images
        if (nr > questions.Count)
                                 {
                                  button1.Enabled = false;
                                  }
        else
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int x;
            do   { x = r.Next(questions.Count); } 
                  while (questions[x].displayed == true);
            textBox1.Text = questionText;// now it doesn't appear the index;thank you
            radioButton1.Text = questions[x].answer1; // is not from the current
                                                      //  question
            radioButton2.Text = questions[x].answer2;// is not from the current
                                                     //  question
            questions[x].displayed= true;
            current_question = x;
        }
      }
```

Comment: How are you filling your `questions` collection, and how are you filling your `ImageList`?

Comment: Do your questions in your text file line up 1-to-1 with how your images are included in your ImageList? Like, the first question is the first image, the second question the second image, etc? If not, how do you associate them?

Answer (score 2):

You could try including the image index in your quiz.txt file:

> 3:What is the foo in the bar?
>   10:How can you add a widget?
>   4:Why pick a bar over a foo?

Then, at the point in your program when you pick your random question you could extract the image index and the text of the question:

```
int x = r.Next(questions.Count); 
// intrebari is a variable of class 'question'
string line = intrebari[x].text; 
// find the colon
int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':'); 
// the image index is left of the colon
int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter)); 
// and the question itself is right of the colon
string questionText = line.Substring(delimiter + 1); 
// set the image in the picture box
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imageIndex];
```

So then `questionText` is the string you display and `imageIndex` you can use to pick the correct image: `imageList1.Images[imageIndex]` to assign to your PictureBox.

If you are still displaying the questions and the image index it means you are displaying the `line` variable when you should be displaying the `questionText` variable.  Also, beware of the "off by one" error when assigning image indexes to your questions because indexing starts at 0.

**Edit**

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
    if (nr > questions.Count) 
    { 
        button1.Enabled = false; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Random r = new Random(); 
        int x; 
        do   { x = r.Next(questions.Count); }  
              while (questions[x].displayed == true); 

        string line = questions[x].text; 
        int delimiter = line.IndexOf(':'); 
        int imageIndex = int.Parse(line.Substring(0, delimiter)); 
        string questionText=line.Substring(delimiter + 1); 
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[imageIndex];//I still have problems with        

        textBox1.Text = questionText;// now it doesn't appear the index;thank you 
        radioButton1.Text = questions[x].answer1; // is not from the current 
                                                  //  question 
        radioButton2.Text = questions[x].answer2;// is not from the current 
                                                 //  question 
        questions[x].displayed= true; 
        current_question = x; 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: @Bodgan, you need to click the 'edit' button under your question and include your pertinent code because I can't figure out what's going wrong when I can't see your code.

Comment: @Bogdan,See my edit. The problem was your current_question and the do-while loop. You had the image for the current_question, which was the last question, and your do-while loops to a new question. It's helpful to step through the code line-by-line with a debugger watching the variables! I hope all this answered your original question.

Comment: @Brad_Rem, thank you so much! Each image is associated with its question! But the program doesn't want to follow the same algorithm if I select a new quiz with the help of " private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) ". The quiz doesn't stop after 10 questions.It goes on, it repeats the questions and at the question 17 it locks. Would you like to help me, please?

Comment: @Bogdan, in your buton1 click handler else clause you need to add `nr++;` immediately before `current_question = x`; You may also have to change your if nr > questions.Count to nr > = questions.Coutn but again, you should step through the code in the debugger to see what happens.

Comment: @Brad_Rem I made this modifications. Then, after I stepped through the code, I saw: when I resolve the quiz for the first time:questions.Count=10; when I resolve it for the second time: questions.Count=20; when I resolve it for the third time: questions.Count=30; Would you like to tell me how can I set questions.Count=10, please ? Thank you.

Comment: @Bogdan, sounds like each time you resolve a question, you read the data from your file all over again and add it to your collection.